TLS and plain text traffic to the same sidecar
I am trying to transition my legacy applications to the service mesh.  To do this,  I would like to support both plaintext traffic and TLS traffic into the Pod so that application in the same namespace that have not transitioned to the Service Mesh can still call my application.  So,  I am trying to configure the Sidecar to accept both types of protocols and then terminate and pass it to the underlying container.  However,  I cannot seem to get it to work correctly.
Here is what I have tried:
- apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1 
  kind: PeerAuthentication
  metadata:
    name: servicetoservice-mesh
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: hello-world
    mtls:
      mode: STRICT
    portLevelMtls:
      443:
        mode: STRICT
      8080: 
        mode: DISABLE   

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
    ......
  spec:
    ports:
      - port: 8080
        name: http
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8080
        appProtocol: HTTP
      - port: 443
        name: https
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8080
        appProtocol: HTTPS      

This seems to allow plaintext on 8080,  but I get protocol errors for 443/HTTPS.

Please use mode as "PERMISSIVE" which will allow both plain text and mTLS traffic.  More details of declaring "PeerAuthentication" are in istio documentation
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: servicetoservice-mesh
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  mtls:
    mode: PERMISSIVE
  portLevelMtls:
    443:
      mode: STRICT
    8080:
      mode: DISABLE   


I'm not really sure that solves my problem since I still want STRICT on 443 ports.

First level mode will be PERMISSIVE which will allow both plaintext and mTLS and at port level it will be STRICT for 443 and 8080 it will be plaintext
